# Part of click function not working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of `<td>` elements within a table that, in my context, are "slots" of a space that a user can select. Each slot has an attribute (`data-slot-stamp`) that holds the ID (a timestamp) of the slot. When the user clicks a slot, that timestamp is added to another element's (`.addButton`) attribute `data-selected-slots`. If the user clicks the slot again, that slot is to be removed from the `.addButton`'s data-selected-slots attribute.
The below snippet is working, except on the first click IF a user is removing the slot from their selection.

Example of desired behavior:

- User clicks any slot
- The value of that slot's data-slot-stamp attribute is added to the value of the data-selected-slots attribute of the .addButton element
- If the user clicks that same slot again, the value of that slot's data-slot-stamp attribute should be removed from the value of the data-selected-slots attribute of the .addButton element.

What's happening in my case:

- User clicks any slot
- The value of that slot's data-slot-stamp attribute is added to the value of the data-selected-slots attribute of the .addButton element
- If the user clicks that same slot again (but ONLY if it was the FIRST slot clicked since a page refresh) the value of that slot's data-slot-stamp attribute is NOT removed, but stays in the value of the data-selected-slots attribute.
- On subsequent clicks of any slot, the functionality works as expected but the initially clicked slot's data is never removed.

Html Structure:

```
<table class="spacesTable">
          <tr>
                <td class="slot used unselected" data-slot-stamp="123456789">
                Slot 1
                </td>
                <td class="slot used unselected" data-slot-stamp="987654321">
                Slot 2
                </td>
                <td class="slot used unselected" data-slot-stamp="654321987">
                Slot 3
                </td>
                <td>
                     <div class="addButton" data-selected-slots="">
                     Add Button
                     </div>
                </td>
          </tr>
     </table>
```

Relevant jQuery:

```
    $('.spacesTable').on('click', '.slot.used', function() {
        var curAtts = $(this).siblings('.addButton').attr('data-selected-slots');
        var clickedStamp = $(this).attr('data-slot-stamp');

        if ($(this).hasClass('unselected')) {
$(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('unselected');
            //Add to the values stored in the data-selected-slots attr of the button for this row
            var spacer = ',';
            if (!curAtts) {
                curAtts = '';
                spacer = '';
            }
            $(this).siblings('.addButton').attr('data-selected-slots', clickedStamp+spacer+curAtts);

        } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
$(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
            //check to see if the slot timestamp is in the button's data-selected-slots attr, and if so, remove it
            var findStamp = curAtts.indexOf(clickedStamp);
            if (findStamp != -1) {
                curAtts = curAtts.replace(clickedStamp+',','');
                $(this).siblings('.addButton').attr('data-selected-slots', curAtts);
            }

        }
     });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also need a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve in more specific terms

Comment: First thing why you need two selector 'unselected' and 'selected'? If It does not have selected class, it means it not selected.
If 'background-color' is changing, it is mean you are missing some logic in other code.

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated the questions to hopefully be more clear and concise. Thanks.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Because in my CSS I have styling for .selected, .unselected, as well as neither, so three states are needed for this scenario.

Comment: You have NOT added the code that is relevant, so no, you haven't clarified.  Please **include the code** (that's what a Minimal, Compete, and Verifiable example is).

Comment: I believe I have now, thanks. The html and jquery are all I have to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ","

change this:

```
curAtts = curAtts.replace(clickedStamp+',','');
```

with something like:

```
if (curAtts.indexof(",") > 0) {
    curAtts = curAtts.replace(clickedStamp+',','');
}else{
    curAtts = curAtts.replace(clickedStamp,'');
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, this led me in the right direction, which was to allow the hanging comma at the end of the string and strip it out later when getting the value.